# Rails ActiveRecord Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find

Single Table Inheritance using ActiveRecord. Since we can use `@test = Employee.all` and find all the employees created. How does rails do this? Since we only use a User Table. How does it know about employees and retrieve only employees? Rails Magic? Explanation anyone? Thank you in advance.

```
Base Class : Person (inherits ActiveRecord)
Sub-Class: Employee, Supervisor, Manager (each inherit Person)
```

So my Person table needs to have a _type and _id field to make the table polymorphic.

My next question is how do I get Employee Associated to the Person table and when you save an employee, how do you get it to actually put in Employee in the person_type field?

Comment: If you want to ask a follow-on question you would be better off asking a new question and linking back to this one in reference. It will be more visible that way and you won't get the problem of people having to update their answers. Also, as you've accepted an answer to this question already people will be even more unlikely to check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To indicate to Ruby on Rails that the
> users table needs to support Single
> Table Inheritance you need to add a
> column named ‘type’ to the users
> table. Here is my users table
> definition:
>
> CREATE TABLE users (    id INT NOT
> NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    user
> VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,    pass
> VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,    type
> VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,    PRIMARY KEY  (id) );
>
> In the column named type you
> should store the name of the class,
> the class type, that should be used
> for each user. To mark an certain user
> as an admin set his type to
> ‘Administrator’. By setting a user’s
> type to ‘Administrator’ you are giving
> him full administrator privileges as
> defined in your Administrator model
> class.

http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, once i have the fields _type and _id, how do I actually get the association placed into that column?

Comment: Oh an actually field named "type" I was thinking of table inheritance with using _type. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Single table inheritance uses a `type` column on the table to indicate the type of the object. `ActiveRecord` knows that your `Employee` class is using single table inheritance (it has no matching table and the users/people table has a type column).

So when you ask for `Employee.all` it knows to looks for all entries in the users/people table where `type == 'Employee'`.

If you look at the logs the SQL will be displayed for these queries and you'll see the 'magic' happening.